# How to INSERT values to table after updating information SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table invoice
(
inv_number CHAR (10) not null,
inv_date VARCHAR2 (8) not null,
order_number VARCHAR2 (10) not null,
r_date VARCHAR2 (8) not null,
f_date VARCHAR2 (8) not null,
arrive_time NUMBER not null
);
```

This is my INVOICE table

And I added this to it

```
select * from invoice;
ALTER table invoice add inv_total NUMBER (2);
```

This is the result after       (select * from invoice)

[image]

How can I re-enter values into the "invoice table" without getting an error?
I assume I have to update it somehow to be able to enter the values.
Thank you.

Update: This is the INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO invoice (inv_number, inv_date, order_number, r_date, f_date) VALUES ('S104011041',TO_DATE ('15/03/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'S004-011152',TO_DATE ('15/03/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE ('15/03/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.  Do you want to know how to set a value for the new column `inv_total` in the existing rows?  The short answer to that is use an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Oh wow, that helped unintentionally
Thank you very much.

Comment: do you want to insert the same rows twice? or you want jast update the rows an put the value into new column?